# $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is a global frame on $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, vector-fields, spheres

Id like you to check this:

> Given
>
> $X_1(w,x,y,z)=(-x,w,-z,y)$
>
> $X_2(w,x,y,z)=(-y,z,w,-x)$
>
> $X_3(w,x,y,z)=(-z,-y,x,w)$
>
> prove that:
>
> 1. they are $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ vector fields on $S^3$;
> 2. $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is a global frame on $S^3$.
> 3. What can we say about $TS^3$?

My idea of the solution is:

1. $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ vector fields on $S^3$ since I can compute every partial derivatives, for all $p\in S^3$. Moreover if $p=(w,x,y,z)\in S^3$ then
   \begin{eqnarray}
   & &(w,x,y,z)\cdot(-x,w,-z,y)=-wx+xw-zy+zy=0\\
   & &(w,x,y,z)\cdot(-y,z,w,-x)=-wy+xz+yw-zx=0\\
   & &(w,x,y,z)\cdot(-z,-y,x,w)=-wz-xy+xy+zw=0\\
   \end{eqnarray}
   so $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are tangent to $S^3$ for all $p\in S^3$.
2. $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is a global frame because they are linearly independent since $aX_1+bX_2+cX_3=0$ iff $a=b=c=0$ for all $p\in S^3$.
3. Since there exists a global frame on $S^3$, that is a global frame on $TS^3$, we can say that $TS^3$ is trivial.

Is everything all right?

Thank you so much

Comment: The ideas are certainly correct.

Comment: You missed one point: In order to show that these are vector fields on $S^3$, you need to show that each one is actually tangent to $S^3$.

Comment: @Jack Lee I've edited my question. Is it right like this? Thank you

Comment: It basically looks OK. There's still one very small mathematical gap: Your argument in part 1 shows that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are smooth vector fields on $\mathbb R^4$, not on $S^3$. How do you deduce smoothness on $\mathbb R^3$? Also, one grammatical point: One says "there exists a global frame," not "it exists a global frame."

Comment: @Jack Lee Would it be enough if I considered local coordinates on $S^3$, given by the stereographic projection for example, or I need to prove that $X_i$, satisfy Leibniz?

Comment: @Jack Lee thank you for the grammar correction, unfortunately my English is not as I'd like it.